# Ошибка в подгрузке чанков, что не так?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, redux

Добрый день всем!
Есть проблема, и никак не могу найти решения, т.к. давно уже напрямую дело с настройкой webpack'ом не имел.

Приходят ошибки от пользователей с портала, где подключены мои виджеты написаные на React. 
К примеру:

```
{
  "message": "Loading chunk 0 failed.",
  "stack": "Error: Loading chunk 0 failed.\n    at HTMLScriptElement.n (http://<мой урл>/widget/media/index.js:2:500)"
}
```

а иногда приходит и такая ошибка, скажем с другого поддомена третьего уровня, где так же располагаются виджеты

```
{
  "message": "Loading chunk 1 failed.",
  "stack": "Error: Loading chunk 1 failed.\n    at HTMLScriptElement.n (http://<мой урл>/widget/media/index.js:2:500)"
}
```

Обновляется на продакшене это по такой цепочке: вначале на сервере запускается команда **build:prod** которая в пэкейдже вот такая `"build:prod": "npm run lint && npm test && webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js"`, затем сам **webpack.config.prod.js**, который в свою очередь содрежит в себе вот такой код

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const pkg = require('./package.json');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        index: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'index.js')
    },

    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
        filename: '[name].js',
        chunkFilename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: '/widget/media/'
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: 'babel-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
                use: 'file-loader?name=img/[name].[ext]'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'css-loader',
                            options: {
                                sourceMap: false,
                                modules: true,
                                minimize: true,
                                localIdentName: '[hash:base64:7]'
                            }
                        },
                        'postcss-loader'
                    ]
                })
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css'),
        new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compress: { warnings: false },
            comments: false
        }),
        new webpack.BannerPlugin(`${pkg.name}-${new Date()}. RELEASE.`),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production')
            },
            PROJECT_ENV: JSON.stringify('production')
        })
    ]
};
```

В самом файле index.js, который располагается в папке src, который указан как entry index у меня такой код

```
import 'babel-polyfill';
import datasetPolyfill from 'element-dataset';
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';
import Orders, { initAction } from './features/orders';
import Returns, { initAction as returnInit } from './features/returns';

datasetPolyfill();

const features = {
    orders: {
        root: Orders,
        init: initAction
    },
    returns: {
        root: Returns,
        init: returnInit
    }
};

const containers = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[data-feature]'));

containers.forEach(container => {
    const Feature = features[container.dataset.feature];

    if (Feature) {
        store.dispatch(Feature.init(JSON.parse(container.dataset.state)));

        render(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Feature.root />
            </Provider>,
            container
        );
    }
});
```

В этом коде, я нахожу все мои фичи со спец якорем. Далее, в файле **import Orders, { initAction } from './features/orders'** у меня вот такой код

```
import errorAction from 'rossko-orders/lib/actions/error';
import AsyncComponent from '../../components/async-wrap';

function importFunc() {
    return import(/* webpackChunkName: "orders" */ 'rossko-orders');
}

export initAction from 'rossko-orders/lib/actions/init';
export default AsyncComponent(importFunc, errorAction);
```

Тоже самое у меня и с **import Returns, { initAction as returnInit } from './features/returns';**

Судя по тому какой вал ошибок, происходит это не у всех пользователей, а только лишь у какой-то части. Более того, на тестовом окружении таких ошибок небыло вообще.

Сперва были подозрения, что происходит это только на старых браузерах, типа IE или на мобилках, но оказалось, что это не так и происходит на не старых браузерах.

```
Headers: Cache-Control: no-cache; Connection: close; Pragma: no-cache; Content-Type: application/json; Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*; Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br; Accept-Language: ru,en;q=0.8; Cookie: ym_uid=149837534368628556; ga=GA1.2.1338437862.1512111490; _gid=GA1.2.386643296.1513581524; Host: returns; Referer: http://< url >/personal/orders/; User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.137 YaBrowser/17.4.1.1026 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36; Origin: http://< url >; Content-Length: 162; Authorization-Domain: http://< url >; Authorization-Session: < сессия >.
{
  "message": "Loading chunk 0 failed.",
  "stack": "Error: Loading chunk 0 failed.\n    at HTMLScriptElement.n (http://< url >/widget/media/index.js?:2:500)"
}
```

Я в тупике и не знаю в чем причина и как ее исправить. Поэтому любая помощь будет ценной и полезной.

Comment: в гугле вываливаются некоторые подобные сообщение, не уверен, сможет ли это помочь... https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=Loading+chunk+1+failed&oq=Loading+chunk+1+failed&aqs=chrome..69i57.413j0j7&client=ubuntu&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: К сожалению не нашел для себя ответа... Поэтому задал вопрос тут. С описанием своей проблемы.

Comment: ну как вариант - это расширения браузеров, блокирующие вашу подгрузку... Вам надо как то понять, какое стечение обстоятельств влияет на появление недуга)

Comment: Тоже подумал об этом. А есть идеи по поводу того, как понять, расширения блокируют или нет?

Comment: Ну как, получилось?

Comment: Как понять, расширения блокируют или нет, довольно просто - выключить расширения и проверить :)

Comment: @DanielKhoroshko дело в том, что я даже на тестовом окружении включил отсылку ошибок, но как бы я не пробовал, ко мне не прилетает ошибка с тестового. С адблоками пробовал и т.д., но сообщение упорно не лезет с ошибкой. Но зато от пользователей приходит. Не часто, раза 3-4 в час, но прилетает. Это исходя из того, что пользователей тысячи, заказов с сайта тоже весьма прилично, поэтому счет идет на десятые процента, а может и меньше. Вопрос в том, что не так и что блокирует подгрузку? Показывал свой код приятелям, все говорят, что ошибки нет. Как можно еще попробовать заллогировать погуще?

Comment: Не приходит ли от пользователей информация об их окружении? Хотя бы версия браузера.. может это 9й IE или что то подобное?

Comment: @DanielKhoroshko Приходит конечно. Например  "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36 OPR/36.0.2130.80", или  "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36 OPR/49.0.2725.64", и еще пример  "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36 OPR/36.0.2130.80",

Comment: @DanielKhoroshko По вебпаку и коду всё верно. Показывал свой код нескольким людям, они тоже не нашли ошибки. Гугл вообще внятных ответов не дает. Что печально. Более того, я не знаю как эта ошибка проявляется у пользователей, может быть они ее не замечают, а может быть и замечают. Если это никак не проявляется в плане работоспособности, то тогда это можно было бы поставить в статус "Модет быть решение поже найду", но опять же я не знаю, видно это как-то пользователю или нет... :(